# Why can't I select elements from Instagram using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, bots, instagram

I have this piece of code I wrote a few months back, which was working as far as I can remember. I tried to run it today and it doesn't work any more. Does anyone have any idea why? The problem lies in the `automate(browser)` function, when trying to select the like button, Selenium is unable to find it. I tried using CSS selectors, full XPATH and XPATH but it just won't work. It seems weird because it works when selecting the `log in` and `not now` buttons, as well as the number of posts and the first post. It is when I open the first post that I seem to be unable to select anything. No like button, no comment area, no next button.

Any help will be appreciated!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By; from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

USERNAME = YOUR_USERNAME
PASSWORD = YOUR_PASSWORD

def login():
    # Log into instagram
    options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    browser = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
    browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/'); browser.implicitly_wait(3)
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'username').send_keys(USERNAME); browser.implicitly_wait(3)
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'password').send_keys(PASSWORD); browser.implicitly_wait(3)
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='loginForm']/div/div[3]/button").click(); browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    # Check if logged in successfully
    try:
        if browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='slfErrorAlert']"):
            browser.close(); exit('Error: Login information is incorrect')
    except: print(f"Successfully logged into {USERNAME}")
    
    # Close pop-up and return
    try: browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]').click()
    except: pass
    return browser

def automate(browser):
    likes = comments = errors = 0

    # Prompt for target username and comment text
    target = input("Target's username: ")
    comment = input("Comment: ")

    # Go to user and click first post
    browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + target); browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    # Get account's number of posts
    totalposts = int(browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[1]/span/span').text)

    # Open first post
    browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"_9AhH0").click(); browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    # Like (and comment) every post
    for post in range(totalposts):
        try:
            # Check if post is already liked based on the button's color, like it if not
            like_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/span/svg')
            if like_button.getAttributes("color") == "#ed4956":
                print("Already liked (will not be commented either)")
                browser.find_element_by_link_text(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next').click()
            else:
                browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/').click()
                print("Liked"); likes += 1
        except:
            print("Could not like"); errors += 1
            
            # If post was not already liked, comment it and go to next post
        try:
            browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/").click(); browser.implicitly_wait(3)
            browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea").send_keys(comment + Keys.ENTER); browser.implicitly_wait(3)
            print(f"Commented {comment}"); comments += 1
            browser.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next').click()
        except:
            print("Could not comment"); errors += 1
            browser.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next').click()
    
    # Close browser and return stats
    print('Closing browser...'); browser.close()
    stats = {'liked': likes, 'commented': comments, 'errors': errors}
    return stats

if __name__ == "__main__":
    browser = login()
    stats = automate(browser)
    print(f"Liked: {stats['liked']} | Commented: {stats['commented']} | Errors: {stats['errors']}")
```